# Product listing in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a site that runs on Prestashop 1.6. We were able to install and set up the default shop as well as a couple of multishops. The issue that we are having is that as we continue to create multishops for our locations and add products onto these shops, we want these products to display on our default "Master" shop. Is there a way to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this kind of customization have to be done in code, but it is not very hard. You can built a module to query the products and display it in any of the display hooks, say `displayLeftColumnProduct` or `displayHome`.

The second way is to use override. Overriding `Product` class or the `ProductController` might also works, but here I show you how to do this with overriding.

Looking at the `Product` class, in the `getProducts` method (https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6/classes/Product.php#L1069) there is a call to `Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p')` to create the JOIN for shop. To by pass that, we need to override the `Shop::addSqlAssociation` method (https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6/classes/shop/Shop.php#L954) and check if the current shop is the "Master", for example:

```
class Shop extends ShopCore {

    public static function addSqlAssociation($table, $alias, $inner_join = true, $on = null, $force_not_default = false)
    {
        // It better to check using URL
        if (self::$context_id_shop == 1) return '';
        return parent::addSqlAssociation($table, $alias, $inner_join, $on, $force_not_default);
    }
}
```